# FastAPI with uvicorn: TLS connection dropped after Client Hello

Tags: ssl, fastapi, uvicorn

I do run a simple FastAPI server listening on https:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload --ssl-keyfile=./certs/app-key.pem --ssl-certfile=./certs/full.chain.pem --port 9063 --host 192.168.2.201 --ssl-version=2
```

It works fine, i can use Postman to access the app via https://192.168.2.201:9063.
But my client is actually a network device (using exactly same API as Postman) and that is failing to establish TLS connection. Device is configured correctly to trust CA certificate. When troubleshooting i have found out what is happening:

- network device establishing TCP connection to 192.168.2.201:9063
- network device sends TLS Client Hello (TLS envelope is version 1.0, but inner Client Hello is version 1.2)
- FastAPI app sends empty ACK and then FIN

So it looks like uvicorn does not like that TLS proposal: version or ciphers (my guess). This is what is happening:

[image]

I have tried all version uvicorn with `--ssl-version=1` but got error `invalid or unsupported protocol version 1`.

When testing with nmap i can see uvicorn is supporting only TLS 1.2 and 1.3:

```
michal@certs % nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 9063 192.168.2.201
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-12-27 12:27 CET
Nmap scan report for ise.example.com (192.168.2.201)
Host is up (0.00024s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|   TLSv1.3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A
```

Is there any way to troubleshoot it ? How to confirm why uvicorn is finishing that TLS session ?

Update: i was able to pass uvicorn argument `--ssl-version=3` which looks like is TLS1.0, but still the network device proposal is rejected by uvicorn.

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved the issue, the problem was in the incompatible ciphers used by default by uvicorn (no match between very specific network device proposal and uvicorn).

Once i have discovered all supported ciphers:

```
import ssl

ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
ciphers = ctx.get_ciphers()

v12ciphers = ":".join([cipher['name'] for cipher in ciphers if cipher['protocol'] =='TLSv1.2'])
print(v12ciphers)
```

And used all of those when starting uvicorn all started to work fine (using TLS 1.2):

```
--ssl-version=5 --ssl-ciphers="ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"
```